# Creating a button what pass a variable to the next page

Tags: php, mysql

I building an inventory management solutions in php for my father's shop. This is the code what lists the inventory in table from MySQL database.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Wrong statement!');
    echo '<table border=1>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Type</th>';
    echo '<th>Name</th>';
    echo '<th>Wholesaleprice</th>';
    echo '<th>Price</th>';
    echo '<th>Supplier</th>';
    echo '<th>Place</th>';
    echo '<th>Place2</th>';
    echo '<th>Count</th>';
    echo '<th>Barcode</th>';
    echo '<th>Last Change</th>';
    echo '<th>Details</th>
    echo '</tr>';       

    while ( ($current_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))!= null) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["ID"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["type"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["name"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["wholeprice"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["price"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["wholesaler"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["whereis"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["whereis2"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["count"] . ' ' .   $current_row["dimension"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["barcode"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $current_row["lastchange"] . '</td>';
            echo '<td> HERE GOES THE BUTTON </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';                                
    mysqli_free_result($res);?>
```

How I can put a button (form or button class), what navigates to the "productdetails.php" and pass the current row's barcode as a variable, too?

I tried:

```
<form action="productdetails.php" method="get">
    <button type="submit" class="button" value="' . $current_row["barcode"] . '">Product Details</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: use JavaScript. Write function in JavaScript that accepts the parameter as argument and call function on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tinkered with it a bit with @Florian's answer and I ended up with this working code snippet:

```
while ( ($current_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))!= null) {
$barcode= $current_row["barcode"];

 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["ID"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["type"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["name"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["wholeprice"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["price"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["wholesaler"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["whereis"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["whereis2"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["count"] . ' ' . $current_row["dimension"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["barcode"] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $current_row["lastchange"] . '</td>';?>
 <td> <form method="post" action='productdetails.php'>
    <input type="hidden" name="barcode" value="<?php echo "$barcode"?>"/>
    <button type="submit" class="button">More>></button> 
    </form></td>
 <?php echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close actualy.
Try it with this code snippet;

```
<form action="productdetails.php?barcode=' . $current_row["barcode"] . '" method="get">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Product Details</button> 
</form>
```

You will then be able to get it in the productdetails.php with $_GET['barcode'].

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but somewhy it's not passing the variable. 
echo '<td> <form action="productdetails.php?barcode=' . $current_row["barcode"] . ' method="get">
<button type="submit" class="button">Product details</button> 
</form></td>';

And I made a small "debugger" in a productdetails.php

<?php $barcode = $_GET['barcode'];
echo "The barcode is: $barcode";?>

Output: The barcode is:

Comment: I think you forgot a double quote after the single quote before method="get". 

It should be $currentrow[...] <dot> <singlqQuote><doubleQuote> method="get"

Comment: I tried that, too but it didn't passed it either. (I don't know why). I tinkered with it and now it's working with method="post" and input type="hidden"